# concatenate several enumerations?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I had to subclass `ResourceBundle` due to our specific needs.

However, to override `getKeys()`, I am a bit in trouble. This `getKeys` needs to somehow concatenate from a map of underlying `ResourceBundle`s. How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT: While submitting I came across an idea. Basically we have for each of our `Module` a `ResourceBundle`, so my code looks like this so far:

```
public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Map.Entry<Module, ResourceBundle> entry : internalMap.entrySet()) {
            Enumeration<String> tmp = entry.getValue().getKeys();
            while (tmp.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = tmp.nextElement();
                keys.add(key);
            }
        }

        return Collections.enumeration(keys);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we finally came up with. There is more code to it but thought it would be fair to share the basics. The solution follows a bit skaffman's proposal.
Thanks to all contributions.

```
public class ChainedResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle implements Enumeration<String> {

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Module, ResourceBundle>> tables;
    private Enumeration<String>                 keys;

    private Map<Module, ResourceBundle>         internalMap    = new HashMap<Module, ResourceBundle>();
    private Map<String, String>                 customizedKeys = new HashMap<String, String>();


    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        tables = internalMap.entrySet().iterator();
        nextTable();
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return keys != null;
    }


    @Override
    public String nextElement() {
        String key = keys.nextElement();
        if (!keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            nextTable();
        }
        return key;
    }

    private void nextTable() {
        if (tables.hasNext()) {
            keys = tables.next().getValue().getKeys();
        } else {
            keys = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is just to manually enumerate over the enumerations, dump them into a collection, then return an enumeration of that collection.

Failing that, you could combine [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) operations to do this, something like this:

```
// the map of enumerations
Map<?, Enumeration<String>> map = ...

// a function that turns enumerations into iterators
Function<Enumeration<String>, Iterator<String>> eumerationToIteratorFunction = new Function<Enumeration<String>, Iterator<String>>() {
   public Iterator<String> apply(Enumeration<String> enumeration) {
      return Iterators.forEnumeration(enumeration);
   }
};

// transform the enumerations into iterators, using the function
Collection<Iterator<String>> iterators = Collections2.transform(map.values(), eumerationToIteratorFunction);

// combine the iterators
Iterator<String> combinedIterator = Iterators.concat(iterators);

// convert the combined iterator back into an enumeration
Enumeration<String> combinedEnumeration = Iterators.asEnumeration(combinedIterator);
```

It's pretty cumbersome, but `Enumeration` is old and rather poorly supported in modern APIs.  It can be slimmed down a bit by judicious use of static imports. You can even do the whole thing in a single function-style statement:

```
Map<?, Enumeration<String>> map = ...

Enumeration<String> combinedEnumeration = asEnumeration(concat(
   transform(map.values(), new Function<Enumeration<String>, Iterator<String>>() {
      public Iterator<String> apply(Enumeration<String> enumeration) {
         return forEnumeration(enumeration);
      }
   })
));
```

This approach has the benefit of being efficient - it does everything lazily, and won't iterate until you ask it to. Efficiency may not matter in your case, though, in which case just do it the simple way.

Comment: Yes, Enumeration is such an old interface that maybe @fablife should just send a MethodNotSupportedException.  It will very likely never be called.

Comment: Finally we did something along these lines, although a bit different. We implemented an own ResourceBundle which holds a Collection of iterators over the single enumerations and implements Enumeration. Thus, we can generate the enumeration when needed. Thanks to all contributors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration. It is part of Java without the need of additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom `Enumeration` implementation that will have a `addAll (Enumeration<E> enumeration)` method. Then call `getKeys()` on all underlying `ResourceBundle` objects, and add them all to a new instance of your own `Enumeration`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Guava's Iterators](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html) class: transform each Enumeration using `forEnumeration`, then `concat` the iterators, and transform the resulting iterator back to an Enumeration using `asEnumeration`.

Or implement an concatenating Enumeration yourself using code similar to Guava's concat method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Vector` like

```
public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
    ResourceBundle parent = this.parent;
    Set<String> keySet = this.handleKeySet();
    List<String> parentKeySet = (parent != null) ? list(parent.getKeys()) : null;
    keySet.addAll(parentKeySet);
    return new Vector<>(keySet).elements();
}
```